# Проблемы с CORS - клиент с axios, сервер node js(не нашёл ответа в других похожих вопросах!)

Tags: node.js, axios, cors

Часть кода на сервере(порт 3003):

```
const app = express();
const http = createServer(app);
const io = createSocket(http);
const cors = require('cors');
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors());
app.get("/handler", handler);
const PORT = 3003;

http.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Server: http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Часть кода на клиенте(порт 3000):

```
axios.post("/handler", postData);
```

Пробовал всё, что возможно, писал в package.json:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:3003",
```

Вручную прописывал заголовки, вместо использования cors(),

Менял:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3003";
```

На:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3003";
```

Но ошибка остается:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:3003/handler' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Причем, до самого коллбэка handler() дело не доходит( что-то по типу console.log() не вызывается, к примеру).
Если же вручную прописывать заголовки и делать middleware для cors, то внутри этого middleware вызывается что-то по типу console.log().

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: @ryzen, к сожалению, пробовал и это)